# Manually overcoming ObjectMapper class not found in in a WAR archive

Tags: maven, jboss, dependency-management, resteasy, jbpm

My build of a Business Central of JBPM is a WAR that is (intermittently?) not finding the class:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper; at 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82) at 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346) at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193) at 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:456) at 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229) at 
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135) at 
...
```

I have placed jackson-core-2.11.3.jar and jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar in the WAR's lib directory so I think ObjectMapper should be found.  But these JAR files are of bundle packaging, so contain their own pom files of dependencies.  I believe the Jackson libraries are likely used elsewhere in the app where no exceptions are thrown.  Is this issue related to RestEasy as a dependency? What is the appropriate way to include these dependencies into the war archive manually - since rebuilding often takes most of the day?

Comment: `since rebuilding often takes most of the day?` Really? How many lines of code are those WAR's build of?

Comment: Probably hundreds of thousands and some of the interface code seems to use plugins to generate source code from parameter files that then get built.  I recall looking at an interrupted build a few weeks ago and there were 196K files (mostly temporary) in the directory I was in.

Comment: I have had projects with 2.5 million lines of code which produces 6 different ear packages within 15 minutes including 21000 unit tests.. If this really take that long check the build machines (what kind of machines / hdd ? SSD ? ). are you using most recent versions of the plugins.. Do you use a repository manager etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I use a repository manager.  I believe they are the most recent versions of the plugins.  I use a Windows machine with 12 cores and lots of memory, but a hard drive (not SSD).  I think the build creates 6 WAR's, only 3 of which are used (others are artifacts of the open source project) and hundreds of JAR files.  Thoughts on the classes not being found (the immediate problem)?

Comment: If you are not sure about the version of the plugins I strongly recommend to check that https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ and upgrade. Furthermore Windows is a problem no SSD in these days is a big issue too. Linux based builds including an SSD are much faster then windows based... Memory ? how much is a lot?....on the old project we had network distributed storage; GigaBit networking etc. Also I would check if it's possible to separate those 196 K files generation into several modules so it could be parallelized.. do you use parallel build in Maven -T ?